# Override the [[bin]] path parameter in `cargo run`

Tags: rust, rust-cargo

I have a local playground setup with a bunch of experiment files (each with a `main()`), where my `Cargo.toml` looks like this:

```toml
[package]
name = "playground"
version = "0.1.0"
edition = "2021"

[[bin]]
name = "playground"
path = "./experiment42.rs"


# See more keys and their definitions at https://doc.rust-lang.org/cargo/reference/manifest.html

[dependencies]
```

Right now, I'm manually changing the `path` parameter when I want to debug one or the other experiment and I want to override it in `cargo run` command.

I tried variants of `--config <KEY=VALUE>` based from [the docs](https://doc.rust-lang.org/cargo/reference/config.html#command-line-overrides) to no avail:

```bash
$ cargo run --config "bin.path = \"./experiment69.rs\""
# still runs experiment42.rs

$ cargo run --config "bin.'cfg(all(name = \"playground\"))'.path = \"./experiment69.rs\""
# still runs experiment42.rs
```

The overall goal is to run different files based on the currently opened file in my editor (which I can send to `cargo run` args). Adding new experiment files without editing `Cargo.toml` would be a nice bonus.

Comment: `cargo run --help` → `--bin [<NAME>]            Name of the bin target to run`

Comment: Oh, you have *one* `[[bin]]` and want to reuse it for different source files... You should have one `[[bin]]` for *each* source file.

Comment: @mkrieger1 the target is the same `playground`. Yea, I want to reuse it

Comment: Okay, however I don't understand why you want to write something like `cargo run --config "bin.path = \"./experiment69.rs\""` instead of `cargo run --bin experiment69`.

Comment: @mkrieger1 I want to be able to add a new experiment w/o editing Cargo.toml, rename the files, etc... Basically, use the file system as the source of truth (if that makes sense).  Also, I'm curious why doesn't `--config` work in this case, does it not support the parameter or am I not using it right

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Cargo [configurations](https://doc.rust-lang.org/cargo/reference/config.html) (`.cargo/config.toml`) are different from the [manifest files](https://doc.rust-lang.org/cargo/reference/manifest.html) (`Cargo.toml`). `--config <KEY=VALUE>` is meant to override the former. A mechanism for overriding manifest values is [proposed](https://github.com/rust-lang/cargo/issues/6583), but not yet implemented.

I ended up running a `sed` command before `cargo` for now, similar to the person in the linked issue:

```bash
sed -i -e 's/^path= .*/path = "%file_path%"/' Cargo.toml
```

Answer (score 3):

Since you want `cargo` to pick up your binary files automatically you could use cargos automatic binary detection by adding them to the directory `cargo` picks binaries up automatically, `src/bin/` then you can remove all `[[bin]]` sections and run it with `cargo run --bin yourbinaryfilename` for the file `src/bin/yourbinaryfilename.rs`

For how to do this automatically for the file you've opened in your editor we'd have to know what editor you're using, but for `vim` you can call cargo with `:!cargo run --bin %:t:r` where `%:t:r` is the root of the current filename.